# Get data of JSON string

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, vuejs2

I need to get the `title` of `interval` but my function returns `undefined`.

**Function**

```
filterByCategories () {
      return _.orderBy(this.meetups.filter(item => {
        console.log('title: ' + JSON.stringify(item.interval.title, null, 4))
```

**JSON (content of `this.meetups`):**

```
[
    {
        "id": "-12345",
        "title": "abcds",
        "description": "Hello3",
        "date": "2023-12-29",
        "location": {
            "color": "grey darken-2",
            "icon": "not_interested",
            "id": "none",
            "title": ""
        },
        "creatorId": "abcd1234",
        "time": "24:00",
        "color": {
            "color": "red darken-2",
            "id": "06",
            "title": "Ret"
        },
        "interval": {
            "color": "green darken-2",
            "icon": "local_activity",
            "title": "Weekly",
            "value": 3
        },
        "statusType": false,
        "pause": false,
        "pushNotification": false
    }
]
```

How to read the title of interval?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I access and process nested objects and arrays?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/how-can-i-access-and-process-nested-objects-and-arrays)

Comment: Seems to work for me: https://jsfiddle.net/omu761pa/

Comment: You can use it without `JSON.strigify` also https://jsfiddle.net/c4r2uajn/

Comment: `this.meetups.filter` will return an empty array because you aren't returning anything inside the callback

Answer (score 0):

Since the json is already parsed, you can simply just access it by it's property name. Keep in mind, the data is within an array so there will be multiple `.interval.title`. Using a for loop is probably a better option here unless you're after a certain index. If you are after a certain index, forget the for loop and just do `json[0].interval.name` (0 being the index you're after);

```js
const json = [
    {
        "id": "-12345",
        "title": "abcds",
        "description": "Hello3",
        "date": "2023-12-29",
        "location": {
            "color": "grey darken-2",
            "icon": "not_interested",
            "id": "none",
            "title": ""
        },
        "creatorId": "abcd1234",
        "time": "24:00",
        "color": {
            "color": "red darken-2",
            "id": "06",
            "title": "Ret"
        },
        "interval": {
            "color": "green darken-2",
            "icon": "local_activity",
            "title": "Weekly",
            "value": 3
        },
        "statusType": false,
        "pause": false,
        "pushNotification": false
    }
];

for (let i = 0; i < json.length; i++) {
  const meetup = json[i];
  console.log(meetup.interval.title);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if there are multiple objects in `meetups`, you can use Array.map to iterate over the array of objects, and print out the value of the `title` property within `interval`?

```
this.meetups.map(obj => {
  console.log(`title: ${obj['interval']['title']}`);
});
```

Or simply this, if there is only 1 object in `meetups`?

```
this.meetups[0]['interval']['title']
```

Demo:

```js
const meetups =[{"id":"-12345","title":"abcds","description":"Hello3","date":"2023-12-29","location":{"color":"grey darken-2","icon":"not_interested","id":"none","title":""},"creatorId":"abcd1234","time":"24:00","color":{"color":"red darken-2","id":"06","title":"Ret"},"interval":{"color":"green darken-2","icon":"local_activity","title":"Weekly","value":3},"statusType":false,"pause":false,"pushNotification":false}];

meetups.map(obj => {
  console.log(`title: ${obj['interval']['title']}`);
});
```

Regarding the code you have provided on your question, I am unsure why did you use [Array.filter()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), as what it does is that it returns a new array based on the callback function you have provided within `filter()`. In addition, stringifying it using [JSON.stringify()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) will turn that array into a string, which kind of defeats the purpose of accessing the values within the array of objects.

Comment: also possible with dot notation : this.meetups[0].interval.title

Comment: Yes, indeed you are right! Thanks for the input, @KamilNaja